# how to Fix com/android/sdklib/util/SparseArray in android

Tags: android

Hi this is first time Problem coming in my Development com/android/sdklib/util/SparseArray
 Error is coming so am Unable to Open My  layout File res folder file please tell me how to Fix it this Error is New for me and i don't know how to Fix it .

Comment: I am also receiving the error in same situation as "An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
com/android/utils/SparseArray". Any solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Sakthimuthiah Try this: on eclipse menu, Help > Check for Updates.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can you please change this comment as answer. Then i will vote it as correct answer

Comment: I had the same issue. Updating the Developer Tools> Android DDMS in eclipse resolved it.