# Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'com.xxx...'. com/android/sdklib/util/SparseArray

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project       'com.xxx.android.xxx'.
com/android/sdklib/util/SparseArray
```

I get this error from today when I try to build the project. This is not only to this Android project I get this for all the projects.

Any idea what has happened? This was working yesterday but today I can't build any project on workspace. 
below is eclipse log file.

```
ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2013-10-07 10:09:12.562
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 75 2013-10-07 10:09:12.562
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project     'com.xxx.android.xxx'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/sdklib/util/SparseArray
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.DynamicIdMap.<init>(DynamicIdMap.java:29)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectResources.<init>(ProjectResources.java:67)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ProjectResources.create(ProjectResources.java:74)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.resources.manager.ResourceManager.getProjectResources(ResourceManager.java:160)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.doClean(PreCompilerBuilder.java:772)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.clean(PreCompilerBuilder.java:741)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
at    org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:513)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:422)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.CleanDialog.doClean(CleanDialog.java:313)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.CleanDialog$1.runInWorkspace(CleanDialog.java:151)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse platform
version=4.2.0.  Android SDK 4.3 and 4.2.2 both I used.
Nothing worked for me in the web. Tried to update the eclipse and many more setting changes as suggested in forums.

Eventually I use a fresh eclipse. That was the only way.

Comment: Nope, neither making a clean install fix this problem, even remove the project and imported again did not fix the problem, the problem only appears to me when using IAPBillingService in a project

Answer (score 1):

on eclipse menu, Help > Check for Updates.

according to the comments on [how to Fix com/android/sdklib/util/SparseArray in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956177/how-to-fix-com-android-sdklib-util-sparsearray-in-android)

Comment: I tried this but it says no updates found. Also there is an error when update. See below.

    Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more   detail. 
     No repository found at http://www.eclipse.org/mpc/archive.php.
     No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/releases.
    No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/.

Answer (score 0):

In my case simillar error was produce by eclipse, when in class i write only

```
import
```

this result in invalid compilation in file below problematic one.